# Compare Path/Check for recently added Files with pathlib

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the past I use `os` for monitor and work with new files. Now I try to use `pathlib` and replace `os`. Is there such an easy way to compare Folders and check for added files?

Here my example with `os`:

```
before = os.listdir(downPath)
# <..doing stuff like downloading a file..>
after = os.listdir(downPath)
change = set(after) - set(before)
if len(change) == 1:
    file_name = change.pop()
    print("New File:", file_name)
    print("Renaming")
    os.rename(file_name, basenew)
else:
    print("ERROR: More than one file or no file downloaded")
```

I try to use

```
cwd = Path.cwd()

before = list(Path(cwd).rglob('*'))
print(before)
# ... and so on like above
```

but `list` return one or multiple `path`-element like that: 
`[PosixPath('/home/user/example.txt')]`
so i can't use it with the same procedure i use with `os` (`change = set(after) - set(before)`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get what you had previusly by adding one step after getting the array of `PosixPath` objects by calling the `PosixPath.as_posix()` method. This returns the `Return the string representation of the path with forward (/)` from the docs. Then call `os.basename` on the path and you're back to where you were with `os.listdir()`.

```
>>> cwd = Path.cwd()

>>> before = list(Path(cwd).rglob('*'))
>>> # Overwrite before with
>>> before = [os.path.basename(file_.as_posix()) for file_ in before]
>>> # Proceed as done before and do the same for after list
```

Comment: Thank you. 
I remove ```os.basename``` because I like to work without ```os```. But thats okay because in my project i don't need the basename.